# Fazer busca pelo title do option usando selec2

Tags: html-select, jquery-select2

Tenho um elemento select e preciso fazer a busco dos itens (options) não só pelo texto, mas também pelo title (ou qualquer outro atributo), já consegui colocar o title para aparecer quando se expande o elemento, mas não consigo fazer uma busca no mesmo.

Estou usando o plugin [select2](http://select2.github.io/select2/) na versão 3.5.2

```
<select id="estado" class="form-control">
    <option value="SP" title="São Paulo">SP</option>    
    <option value="RJ" title="Rio de Janeiro">RJ</option>
    <option value="SC" title="Santa Catarina">SC</option>    
</select>

$("#estado").select2({

    formatResult : function(item) {
        var markup = '<div class="row">' +
             '<div class="col-lg-12">' + item.text + '</div>' +
             '</div>' +
             '<div class="row">' +
             '<div class="col-lg-12 text-muted">' + item.element[0].title + '</div>' +
             '</div>';

          return markup;
    }
});
```

**Segue o exemplo rodando no [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lnx7nhh0/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customize o matcher do select2. Usando o seu exemplo:

```js
$("#estado").select2({

  formatResult : function(item) {
            var markup = '<div class="row">' +
                 '<div class="col-lg-12">' + item.text + '</div>' +
                 '</div>' +
                 '<div class="row">' +
                 '<div class="col-lg-12 text-muted">' + item.element[0].title + '</div>' +
                 '</div>';

              return markup;
  },
  matcher: function(term, text, opt) {
       return text.toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())>=0
           || opt.attr("title").toUpperCase().indexOf(term.toUpperCase())>=0;
  }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/22cuj35L/1/